# Android: determine wether broadcast was received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on a chat application where pictures are discussed.
When I receive a c2dm message, the payload contains the message and an md5 which identifies the picture this message is about. When a ChatActivity with a matching md5 is in foreground I want to only play a sound. When it is not, I want to add a notification to the notification bar.

This is the same behaviour as with whatsapp. How to implement this?

Comment: What have u tried so far for this?

Comment: Since only one instance of ChatActivity can exist, I tried this hack: I made the md5 member of ChatActivity public static. Whenever I receive a message I compare the received md5 with the Activity's md5. This works in most cases. When no ChatActivity has been started, the md5 is null, when an activity is active, the md5 is the md5 of displayed picture. I could turn the md5 back to null in onPause() of activity and restore it in onResume(). I guess this is acceptable. But the limitation is that I can never have multiple instances of chatactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the `ChatActivity` register a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the C2DM message, in addition to having your existing manifest-registerd `BroadcastReceiver` for the C2DM message. Have the `IntentFilter` used by the `ChatActivity` in `registerReceiver()` use a positive value for `setPriority()`, as the default is 0. Use `registerReceiver()` in `onResume()` or `onStart()`, and use `unregisterReceiver()` in `onPause()` or `onStop()`.

The result is that when the C2DM message arrives, if your `ChatActivity` is in the foreground, it will get the message first, due to the higher priority. It can do the check to see if the message is about its image. If it is, `ChatActivity`'s `BroadcastReceiver` can call `abortBroadcast()`, to prevent your standard-priority manifest-registered receiver from getting the broadcast. Hence, if your manifest-registered receiver *does* get the broadcast, you know there was no relevant `ChatActivity` in the foreground, and it can raise the `Notification`.

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Ordered) that demonstrates most of this. The broadcast is coming from the app itself, rather than C2DM, but the rest of the structure is pretty much the same.